# How to denormalize neural net predictions after normalizing the input data?

Tags: python, data-analysis, backpropagation

The project we are working on is "Software Effort Estimation using Backpropagation algorithm".

For this project, the neural network is trained using backpropagation algorithm. We used a code which takes iris dataset for training the neural network. The activation function we used is the tangent (tanh) function which has a range of [-1, 1].

The Iris data set has 4 inputs and 1 output (species to which the input belongs to). The 4 inputs are sepal length, sepal width, petal length, and petal width. These variables according to the values are then categorized into the 3 species (setosa, versicolor, and veronica). In the data set, these species are represented in binary as (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1) respectively. All the outputs values are in the range of 0 to 1.

Our project is on Software Effort Estimation so we replaced the dataset with the COCOMO81 data set. The input and output variables are larger in number, ranging up to 2000. In the code, normalization is used to normalize these values, for them to be in the range of -1 to 1 (using the tangent activation function). This works fine for training the neural network, but due to this normalization, we are unable to know the original values of the output values as it is also in normalized form.

The original value is needed to compare it with the obtained output of COCOMO2 model to prove that our model is better. For this, we think we need to denormalize the output values, however, we are unsure about what to do about the output values.

Comment: Hi there, please put some effort into making sure your question looks okay and is answerable. Use proper grammar, capitalization, spelling etc. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Suresh Reshu, welcome on StackOverflow and its community. If I understand well, you are not asking how to code/program a well defined operation to inverse the normalization but rather which operation should be applied. Am I right ? If so, this is more a question about statistical methodology and I would recommend to use the more appropriate website : https://stats.stackexchange.com/. It is also part of stackexchange.com but is dedicated to stats questions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I found out a related question in stats.exchange.com : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66820/denormalize-value-after-prediction/177702#177702